# Partial Fractions

Tags: calculus, integration

I am working on some online calculus 2 partial fraction problems and I just can not seem to do this one. The question reads: "Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{17x^2}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}\, dx$."

I approached the problem by setting $\frac{17x^2}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}= \frac{A}{x+1} +\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}$. I then set $x=-1$ and solved for $A$ to get $A=17/2$. Wolframalpha was able to give me the correct answer to be: $(-17/4)(-\ln|x^2+1|-2\ln|x+1|+2\arctan(x))$, but I am not completely sure how they arrived  at that answer after solving for A. I would be so grateful if someone could help walk me through the rest of this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, we've found $A = \dfrac{17}2$.

We also know  $$A(x^2 + 1) + (Bx + C) (x + 1) = 17x^2$$

Now, if you want to stick with *real valued* $x$, first let $x = 0$

Then $$\underbrace{\frac{17}2}_{A} + C = 0 \iff C = -\frac{17}{2}$$

Now, let $x = 1$:

$$\underbrace{17}_{2A}+ 2B + 2C = 17 \iff 2B + 2C = 0 \iff B = -C = \frac{17}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Now set $x=i$ and you get 
$$Bi+C=-\frac{17}{i+1}=\frac{17}2(i-1)$$
hence you find the value of $B$ and $C$ simultaneously.

Notice that
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\arctan x+C$$
and
$$ \int\frac{x\,dx}{x^2+1}=\frac12\ln(x^2+1)+C$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: is there any other way to approach this problem? I'm just really trying to avoid setting x=i, because my teacher said that he prefers we don't do that for these problem sets.

Comment: Yes 
$$A+B=\lim_{x\to\infty}x F(x)$$
where $F$ is the given fraction and finaly to figure out $C$:
$$0=F(0)=A+C$$

Comment: @user124539 You can use two real values for $x$, say $x = 0, x = 1$, and using your value of $A$, obtain two equations in two unknowns (which are B, C), and then solve for $B$, $C$.

Comment: @amWhy If you have time, do you think you can help me solve for B and C by using two real values for x? I really don't want to be a bother, but this problem is really confusing me so I was hoping to get a step by step kind of answer so that I can see exactly how to lay out the whole problem to solve it correctly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes, see my answer: I chose $x = 0$ which determines $C$, and then $x = 1$, using our obtained values for $A, C$.

Comment: Good points Sami :+)

Comment: @amWhy thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it!

Comment: @user124539 You're welcome.